# Which is the correct value for Tx version in tx messages of bitcoin pcap?

Tags: transactions, transaction-version

Recently, I researched TX messages in the bitcoin protocol and captured some bitcoin traffic in which the version field of a TX message in a specific packet was `2`. The [Transaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction) page of the Bitcoin wiki mentioned that the tx version is currently `1`.

I checked out that packet and I found that it is a valid packet and its value and the generated output address from that tx message is valid.

Comment: That is outdated. Since the implementation of BIP-68 transactions have v2

Comment: @UgamKamat So, it means that now we have two valid version, V1 = 1 and V2 = 2. is it correct?

Comment: yes. Transaction can have either version 1 or 2. However, if you use `OP_CSV` in your transaction, then the transaction versioning MUST be v2. If your transaction does not have `OP_CSV` then v1 and v2 transactions have the same meaning.